# Python Regex for numbers and not string containing numbers (see example)

Tags: python, regex, string

I would like to match number strings like '76' but not '76er'

I've tried the following, and experimenting with [^a-z]
so I don't capture a-z characters after the 2-3 digits but for some reason not working with my test string

test = "Boston Celtics 112 Philadelphia 76ers 95"

should return ["112", "95"]

```
re.findall(r"\d{2,3}", mystring)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `r"\b\d{2,3}\b"`. `\b` means word boundary.

Comment: thanks Alex i knew i was missing some special regex character!